# AWS SNS with SQS permissions

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-ses, amazon-sns

Looking at [this blog](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=202798) post it seems that I need to open my SNS queue to the world to integrate it with SNS. Is this still the case?

I'm trying to implement automatic bounce handling for SES emails and Amazon [recommend](https://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxJE1JNZ6T9JXK/Handling-Bounces-and-Complaints) using a SNS/SQS pattern but if I understand this correctly it would mean that anyone can effectively remove people from our email list? I can't believe this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

So I found some [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html#SendMessageToSQS.sqs.permissions) which indicates that you can specify a source ARN in the queue permissions:

> Add a condition that allows the action for the topic. Click Add
>   Conditions (optional), select ArnEquals for Condition, select
>   aws:SourceArn for Key, and paste in the topic ARN for Value. Click Add
>   Condition. The new condition should appear at the bottom of the box
>   (you may have to scroll down to see this).